# Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly. Sending crash report to Google. Crash report sent

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to start with flutter , at the first i run `flutter doctor` on cmd it works . 
after i installed the ANDROID SDK the same command `flutter doctor` gives me exception :

```
 Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 3c1505515eaa45d1)
Unhandled exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
#0      List.[] (dart:core/runtime/libgrowable_array.dart:145:60)
#1      AndroidNdk.locateNdk.findNdkMajorVersion.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:222:42)
#2      MapBase._fillMapWithMappedIterable (dart:collection/maps.dart:67:32)
#3      new LinkedHashMap.fromIterable (dart:collection/linked_hash_map.dart:124:13)
#4      AndroidNdk.locateNdk.findNdkMajorVersion (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:219:44)
#5      AndroidNdk.locateNdk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:233:47)
#6      AndroidSdk.locateAndroidSdk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:341:24)
#7      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:99:41)
#8      __InternalLinkedHashMap&_HashVMBase&MapMixin&_LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection/runtime/libcompact_hash.dart:281:23)
#9      AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:87:20)
#10     AppContext.[] (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:114:32)
#11     AppContext.[] (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:113:22)
#12     androidSdk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:20:37)
#13     AndroidLicenseValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:180:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     GroupedValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:318:52)
#15     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#16     GroupedValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:315:36)
#17     Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:116:52)
#18     Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:189:41)
#19     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#20     Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:179:24)
#21     _doctorText.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:188:26)
#22     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
#23     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#24     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:7)
#25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#27     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#28     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#29     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
#30     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#31     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:129:19)
#32     _doctorText (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:187:19)
#33     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#34     _doctorText (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:183:27)
#35     _createLocalCrashReport (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:165:32)
#36     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
#37     _createLocalCrashReport (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:150:37)
#38     _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:120:33)
#39     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#40     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#41     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#42     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#43     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#44     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#45     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#46     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#47     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:28:18)
#48     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:294:13)
#49     CrashReportSender.sendReport (package:flutter_tools/src/crash_reporting.dart)
#50     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#51     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#52     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#53     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#54     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#55     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#56     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#57     Stream.fold.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:724:18)
#58     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#59     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#60     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#61     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#62     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#63     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#64     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:96:11)
#65     _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:23:11)
#66     _StringAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:251:11)
#67     _Utf8ConversionSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:302:20)
#68     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:82:18)
#69     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:141:24)
#70     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#71     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#72     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#73     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#74     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#75     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#76     _ForwardingStream._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:106:10)
#77     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:172:13)
#78     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#79     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#80     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#81     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#82     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#83     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#84     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:96:11)
#85     _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:23:11)
#86     _ByteAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/byte_conversion.dart:62:11)
#87     _FilterSink.close (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:637:11)
#88     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:82:18)
#89     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:141:24)
#90     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#91     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#92     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#93     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#94     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#95     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#96     _ForwardingStream._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:106:10)
#97     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:172:13)
#98     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#99     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#100    _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#101    _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:389:13)
#102    _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:399:15)
#103    _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:283:7)
#104    _SyncStreamController._sendDone (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:772:19)
#105    _StreamController._closeUnchecked (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:629:7)
#106    _StreamController.close (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:622:5)
#107    _HttpParser._closeIncoming (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:1037:23)
#108    _HttpParser._doParse (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:752:11)
#109    _HttpParser._parse (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:318:7)
#110    _HttpParser._onData (dart:_http/http_parser.dart:810:5)
#111    _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#112    _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#113    _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
#114    _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#115    _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#116    _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:764:19)
#117    _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:640:7)
#118    _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:586:5)
#119    _Socket._onData (dart:io/runtime/binsocket_patch.dart:1774:41)
#120    _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#121    _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#122    _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
#123    _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#124    _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#125    _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:764:19)
#126    _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:640:7)
#127    _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:586:5)
#128    _RawSecureSocket._sendReadEvent (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:1004:19)
#129    _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
#130    _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#131    _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
#132    _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
#133    _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#134    _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#135    _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#136    Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libtimer_patch.dart:21:15)
#137    _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
#138    _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
#139    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by going to the projects root directory and running the command

```
flutter clean
```

Hope It Helps.

Comment: but i did not create any project yet